# Missing Organization Feature: MultiCurrency error when trying to create a package version

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, unlocked-package

So, when I'm trying to create a package version, `sfdx` fails with:

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  An error occurred while
> trying to install a package dependency, ID 04XXXXXXXXXX: Missing
> Organization Feature: MultiCurrency

However, MultiCurrency is enabled in my dev hub, in my production org, as well as in my scratch org definition file (basically, everywhere):

```
{
  "orgName": "sadfsdf",
  "edition": "Partner Developer",
  "features": ["MultiCurrency", "CascadeDelete", "DebugApex", "Communities", "AuthorApex", "WorkThanksPref"],
  "settings": {
    "accountSettings": {
      "enableAccountTeams": true
    },
    "chatterSettings": {
      "enableChatter": true,
      "enableOutOfOfficeEnabledPref": true
    },
    "entitlementSettings": {
      "enableEntitlements": true,
      "enableMilestoneStoppedTime": true
    },
    "languageSettings": {
      "enableTranslationWorkbench": true
    },
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "sharingSettings": {
      "enableManagerGroups": true
    },
    "workDotComSettings": {
        "enableWorkThanksPref": true,
        "enableProfileSkills": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Just in case someone else has this problem and finds this post, I'm posting it here for the sake of completeness, this is the `project-scratch-def.json` I ended up with, source given below:

```
{
  "orgName": "sadfsdf",
  "edition": "Partner Developer",
  "features": ["MultiCurrency", "CascadeDelete", "DebugApex", "Communities", "AuthorApex", "WorkThanksPref"],
  "settings": {
    "accountSettings": {
      "enableAccountTeams": true
    },
    "currencySettings": {
      "enableMultiCurrency": true
    },
    "chatterSettings": {
      "enableChatter": true,
      "enableOutOfOfficeEnabledPref": true
    },
    "entitlementSettings": {
      "enableEntitlements": true,
      "enableMilestoneStoppedTime": true
    },
    "languageSettings": {
      "enableTranslationWorkbench": true
    },
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "sharingSettings": {
      "enableManagerGroups": true
    },
    "workDotComSettings": {
        "enableWorkThanksPref": true,
        "enableProfileSkills": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IOQlQAO

Comment: What is the material difference between this version and the file in the question?

Comment: that copy and paste failed me when I created the initial post. Please check the edit history. The "currencySettings" object literal was missing. But my initial post included it because I had it in the clipboard from the page I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: You should fix the question so it includes the original problem and describe the answer in your answer; this would be more useful for those trying to figure out what the solution was.

Comment: but I did? That's why I referred to the edit history.

Comment: Oh, that was my misunderstanding. Again, I'd suggest you cut this down to just the relevant bits, people are unlikely to see what they're missing if you just have a big block of "code".